# How to target/highlight a menu element based on filename?

Tags: php, html, html-lists, conditional-statements, menuitem

I want to grab the end of URL using PHP. Once the end of the URL is extracted, I then want use that information to target the corresponding element in the menu. The highlighted element will then indicate what page the user is currently on. My code that I present does work, but I'm wondering if anyone had another work around on this matter.

```
<?php
* Purpose: Get the url in order to define the what link is active on the 
navbar.
*/

$Home="";
$AboutUs="";
$Coupons="";
$Contact="";
$Services="";
$Appointment="";
$Quote="";

Switch(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) {
    case "index.php": $Home ="class=\"active\"";
    break;
    case "about.php": $AboutUs ="class=\"active\"";
    break;
    case "services.php": $Services ="class=\"active\"";
    break;
    case "coupons.php": $Coupons ="class=\"active\"";
    break;
    case "appointment.php": $Appointment ="class=\"active\"";
    break;
    case "quote.php": $Quote ="class=\"active\"";
    break;
    default: $Contact ="class=\"active\"";
}
?>

<ul>
<li <?php echo $Home; ?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li <?php echo $AboutUs; ?>><a href="about.php">About Us</a> </li>
<li <?php echo $Services; ?>><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
<li <?php echo $Coupons; ?>><a href="coupons.php">Coupons</a></li>
<li <?php echo $Appointment; ?>><a href="appointment.php">Appointment</a</li>
<li <?php echo $Quote; ?>><a href="quote.php"> Quote</a></li>
<li <?php echo $Contact; ?>><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, you have to close your PHP statements before continuing with HTML tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I see a large switch case block, I always suggest a lookup array.  This is going to really tighten up your code and make updating it a breeze.  It also eliminates any typos and unwanted spaces that you may mistakenly add.

Declare the array, with the filenames and text and run a loop to print it to screen.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0722028cfef05504fedf5b45752eb4ea85a6bee1))

```
// $filename=basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
$filename='about.php';  // test with this
//$filename='contact.php';  // test with this
//$filename='fish.php';  // test with this
$listitems=[
    'index.php'=>'Home',
    'about.php'=>'About Us',
    'services.php'=>'Services',
    'coupons.php'=>'Coupons',
    'appointment.php'=>'Apointment',
    'quote.php'=>'Quote',
    'contact.php'=>'Contact Us'
];

echo '<ul>';
foreach($listitems as $file=>$text){
    echo '<li';
        if($file==$filename || ($file=='contact.php' && !isset($listitems[$filename]))){
            echo ' class="active"';
        }
        echo "><a href=\"$file\">$text</a>";
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Output:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="coupons.php">Coupons</a></li>
    <li><a href="appointment.php">Apointment</a></li>
    <li><a href="quote.php">Quote</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

The conditional says:

- If the current `$file` value being delivered by the loop is the same as the `$filename` delivered by `basename()` then activate.
- Otherwise, if the current `$file` value is `contact.php` (the last in the list) and the `$filename` is not in the lookup array, then activate.

Comment: Yes, I agree with using a loop in regards of efficiency but I think the switch/case statement is adequate for a few items. Thank you, I really appreciate your input.

Comment: Yes, the problem was asking for an alternative. I was trying to invoke a discussion on this matter. Yes, your code is lean and professional. Again, thank for your input.